# Calculate height from multiple columns with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

I've been banging my head against a wall for some time now, this is what I'm trying to do:

I have 3 div's, 2 of them have a minimum `height` of `300px`, the 3rd columns needs to be the height of the 2 div's together + a 15px margin.

Here's a small example
http://jsfiddle.net/AAKcJ/4/

So far i've found a way to get the height of one column, but I have no idea how to calculate with it since I cant acces the variable outside of the function as I'm not really experienced with JavaScript.

```
    var style_col1 = $("#column1").css( ["height"] );

    $.each(style_col1, function( prop, value ) {
      var height_col_1 = value;
    });


    var style_col2 = $("#column2").css( ["height"] );

    $.each(style_col2, function( prop, value ) {
      var height_col_2 = value;
    });
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: `$('#column3').height( $('#column1').height() + $('#column2').height() + 15 );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a global variable which is visible in both functions

```
var height = 0;
 $('#column1,#column2').each(function(){
     height += $(this).height();
});

$('#column3').css('height', height+15);
```

or

```
height = $('#column1')height()+$('#column2')height();
$('#column3').css('height', height+15);
```

Comment: Why downvote.Please give me the reason .Dont give just downvote